# How can I persist id when i refresh page?

Tags: reactjs

Currently,I'm trying to store the index and id in localstorage so that i can get the specific id and Index when i refresh the page.
so I tried like this :

### ParentComponent

```js
                          //this index and id is what i want to get ///
  const eachComponent = (index, id, name) => (
    <DataSide id={id} key={index} onClick={() => setShow({ [id]: !name })}>
      <SettingMenu
        show={name}
        chart={chart[index]}
        changeLayout={changeLayout}
        panelId={id}
        panelIndex={index}
        setChangeLayout={setChangeLayout}
      />

      {chartcomponentsEle(
        index,
        id,
        title,
        barData,
        scatterData,
        bubbleData,
        info
      )}
    </DataSide>
  );

  const layout = [
      //this index and id is what i want to get ///
    eachComponent(0, "first", show.first),
    eachComponent(1, "second", show.second),
    eachComponent(2, "third", show.third),
    eachComponent(3, "fourth", show.fourth),
    eachComponent(4, "fifth", show.fifth),
    eachComponent(5, "sixth", show.sixth),
    eachComponent(6, "seventh", show.seventh),
    eachComponent(7, "eighth", show.eighth),
  ];
```

### when i click menu there is Link like this:

```js
...


 <Box>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: `/csvFile/${chart}`,
                state: {
                 
                  panelIndex: panelIndex,
                  panelId: panelId,
                },
              }}
            >
              <span>
                <InsertDriveFileIcon style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
                <p>csv파일</p>
              </span>
            </Link>
          </Box>
```

### this is the child Component where i want to set the id and index to localstorage :

```js
      const { panelId, panelIndex } = location.state;
      const { info } = state;
      const { setInfo, AxisUpdate } = data;
      
      let savedState = JSON.stringify(location.state);
      localStorage.setItem("myState", savedState);
```

So i tried to get the item using `getItem` in the component where there is Link
but it didn't work at all
So I want to know how and where i should use getItem .
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure

```js
localStorage.setItem("myState", savedState);
```

is getting called on click, pls debug.
As localStorage is global, you can easily get it in any scope with  localStorage.getItem("myState");

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, Can I use useState in global to contain the index??

Comment: useState is virtual, it will be lost once you refresh the page

Comment: Thank you for answering Sir.  How can i set  that index in global??

Comment: You can use react context API or any state management library like Redux.